# Leading zeros counter

Tags: floating-point, hardware, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am implementing a normalization unit for floating point and I want to know how to efficiently implement a leading zeros counter?

I know I can write the following, but I was wondering if there is a better method if I am targeting low area and high energy efficiency?:

```
always @(mantissa) begin
  case(mantissa)
    25'b1????????????????????????: newmant = mantissa[24:1];
    25'b01???????????????????????: newmant = mantissa[23:0];
    25'b001??????????????????????: newmant = {mantissa[22:0],1'b0};
    25'b0001?????????????????????: newmant = {mantissa[21:0],2'b0};
    // ... (details ommited for brevity)
  endcase
end
```

Comment: Does your hardware design otherwise need a fast barrel shifter? If so, you could separate out finding the number of bits to shift by, and doing the shift.

Comment: No it does not.  It is focused on low power, low area high energy efficiency.  But are you suggesting pipelineing?

Comment: I'm not sure how well pipelining would fit with your low power requirement. Have you considered multistage leading zero counting - do e.g. a 16 bit left shift on anything with at least 16 leading zeros, then an 8 bit left shift on anything with at least 8 leading zeros after the first step. It would have longer paths, but less fan-out than dealing with each case separately.

Comment: I have considered the idea.  I am just not sure if the synthesis tool would implement this automatically? I have too much faith in the tools I think. Would it be better to have it split with a 12 bit shift and a 12 bit shift?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe try writing it a few different ways and see what looks most reasonable. How easy is it for you to try out the synthesis?

Comment: pretty easy, thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, there's really no magic to a variable shift.  You just have to bite the bullet and throw down the muxes.  In your case however it's not that bad.  A 25b barrel shifter (which as Patricia pointed out your case is only a slight simplification of) should only take ~375 2:1 muxes plus the logic to create the selects.  Not great of course but that shouldn't break the bank for area.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In VHDL (which should be readily portable to Verilog):

```
process
   variable leading_zeros : natural;
begin
   leading_zeros := 0;
   for i in input_vector'range loop
      if input_vector(i) = '1' then
         break;
      end if;
      leading_zeros := leading_zeros + 1;
   end for;
end process;
```

For non-VHDL speakers, all this does is loop over all the bits in `input_vector` from left to right, incrementing a counter each time it sees a `0`.  Once it finds the first `1`, it drops out of the loop, leaving the counter containing the number of leading zeros.

To find out whether that is high-efficiency enough, you'll have to try the synthesis - let us know!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know VHDL though.

Comment: Also, behavior model = bad practice IMO

Comment: @starbox: Can you expand on what you mean by "behavior model = bad practice"?  If you mean "the code above is inefficient", then please demonstrate it.  In my experience it produces the same logic as a variety of other coding styles.  I'd rather go for readable than complex.  Unless you are a real gate-guru, its usually difficult to beat the synthesiser these days (didn't used to be true, but there's a lot of hangover....)

Comment: Hi Martin, from my teachings I have been told that if you don't know what it synthesizes to, then you shouldn't code it up.  You should design first and then implement.  It also doesn't contain structural information.  Truly I guess it is a matter of preference, but in my experience it leads to longer debugging times because it is like writing software when you are trying to design hardware, this leads to problems.  Correct me if I'm wrong though, but that is what I have been taught/experienced.

Comment: I guess there's different levels of "knowing"... I know that'll synthesize to a bag of LUTs which will probably have a critical path that is about as long as the number of bits in the vector - I don't have to know the content of the LUTs or the precise arrangement of them.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need a leading zero counter? Even if you have counted how many zeros in the prefix, at the end you still need the comparators and MUXs to determine how many zeros you have and compute the output. It could waste more for your performance/area due to many 1'b1 adders, MUXs, and comparators.

The for/while loop will be unrolled to 25 steps (according to the width) in the synthesizer.
If you use leading zero counters, your architecture becomes like

```
// you will have 25 mux and adders
always @(mantissa) begin
  leading_zeros = 0;
  // for-loop expanded
  if (mantissa[24] == 1)
    disable count_n_2;
  else begin : count_n_2
    leading_zeros ++;
    if (mantissa[23] == 1)
       disable count_n_3;
    else begin : count_n_3
      leading_zeros ++;
      ...
    end
  end
end // always

// you will have 25 comparator and mux
always @(leading_zeros) begin
  case(leading_zeros)
    5'd0: newmant = mantissa[24:1];
    5'd1: newmant = mantissa[23:0];
    5'd2: newmant = {mantissa[22:0],1'b0};
    5'd25: ...
  endcase
end
```

so... you just use your own design and use tool's synthesis/mapping commands to see what it can do to achieve your requirements of area and power.